# Ignoring outermost JSON element using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to parse some JSON using Jackson.  Here is the JSON:
`{
    "data":  {
          "item1":  "Hello",
          "item2":  "World"
     }
}`

I've seen implementations using Jackson where the data field is ignored/not read but the inner elements are still read and stored.  I was wondering how this is achieved?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your mapper configuration you can Unwrap the root element as follows

```
private ObjectMapper rootMapper()
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    return mapper;
}
```

for more detail on this you can look jackson data binder topic

Comment: i added that to my application but it failed with an error "Root name data does not match expected for type"

Comment: You need to add the @JsonRootName annotation, see: https://gist.github.com/araqnid/e174c0bafc8edd05a4a0

Comment: @dlucci or you can specify `withRootName("data")` on the ObjectReader created from the mapper if you don't want to use the annotation